# php file_get_contents returns null when allow_url_fopen is on

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, file-get-contents

I get the warning message: file_get_contents failed to open stream permission denied

I have set all_url_open to on in the php.ini file.

My php file is in my apache server and it is trying to access a url (that returns JSON) from a tomcat server on the same machine.

The code in the php file looks like:

```
  $srcURL = 'http://samemachine:8080/returnjson/';

  $results = file_get_contents($srcURL);
```

I have also tried curl and it returns nothing and doesn't hit the tomcat server either:

```
    function curl($url){
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Language: en-us'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
```

Why is permission denied?

Comment: I assume you mean to say the [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/allow_url_fopen) directive?

Comment: Is it perhaps the remote server returning a 401 access denied error? Have you tried hitting the url in a browser?

Comment: Can you access the file through your browser?

Comment: yes i can hit the url through the browser.  I can also hit it from my local machine with the above php code.  Is it tomcat or apache denying access?

Comment: Use `cURL` to do the request and have it print out the full response including headers to see what the server is doing. Set basic request headers such as `user-agent`. `file_get_contents()` is a lazy way which uses the minimal request headers and so often doesn't work with some web servers.

Comment: I'm doing curl.  I modified the code above to reflect what I'm doing.  I don't get permission denied, but nothing is printed and the tomcat server is never touched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Make sure it's really `allow_url_fopen` and not `all_url_open` as you wrote
- Double-check this by running `phpinfo()`. Make sure it lists the option as enabled. If it doesn't restart your web server
- To debug your curl problem, run Wireshark and watch on the `lo` interface