# file_get_contents is not not capturing required data

Tags: php, file-get-contents

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);

$result = json_decode($data, true);
```

with the above code, I wanted to capture the below output of the url to $data but file_get_contents is not giving anything to $data. Please help me regarding this and also please let me know is there any other way in PHP to do the same.

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Boyces Rd, Wisbech PE13 2JT, UK" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Battersea, London SW8 3QR, UK" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "174 km",
                  "value" : 173989
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "2 hours 42 mins",
                  "value" : 9702
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: If `file_get_contents()` is failing then you'll get a warning. Enable error reporting and check your web server logs.

Comment: Check if **allow_url_open** is set to **on** or you can try to get that contents using cURL. An example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354805/php-file-get-contents-returns-null-when-allow-url-fopen-is-on

Answer (score 0):

You can do this many way

For example:

```
$jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=250x100&chd=t:60,40&chl=Hello|World&chof=json'));
```

with the above method please be sure you server configurations allows "allow_url_fopen".

Using curl can be another solution:

```
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=250x100&chd=t:60,40&chl=Hello|World&chof=json');
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
curl_close($curlSession);
```